# iCarousel Spacing Not Smooth

Tags: ios, swift, image, spacing, icarousel

I am trying to create an 'upload image' system, and I am trying to adjust the space between each images. However, it is not going as planned because when the carousel stops moving, the image always has to go to the front due to an overlap. How can I stop this overlap? Thanks!

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if option == .visibleItems {
        return CGFloat(images.count)
    } else if option == .spacing {
        return value * 0.87
    } else if option == .showBackfaces {
        return 0
    }
    return value
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: getWidths(upTo: index) , y: 0, width: widths[index], height: 200))
    imageView.image = images[index]
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: getWidths(upTo: index) , y: 0, width: widths[index], height: 200)
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
    return imageView
}

func getWidths(upTo index: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var width = CGFloat()

    for i in 0..<index {
        width += widths[i]
    }

    return width

}
```

Here is the result:

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiYSVEFiXE12g_gNyVufJ1LqZMcZtw

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of the carousel, if your type is custom, you should overwrite the function 
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(RPiCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform

In this function, you can use
return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset * self.taskView.itemWidth * offset, 0.0, 0.0); 
This solve my problem